# Is this an improper use of generics with interfaces?

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
interface U {};
type Test<T extends U> = {};
interface TestAgain<Props extends U> {
  Component: Test<Props extends U>; // the closing tag of this line gives an error: '?' expected
}
```

The error is so lacking that I don't know where to begin.

Comment: When you pass the generic, you don't need to pass the constraint. It should be just `Component: Test<Props>`.

Answer (score 0):

`extends` type clause may be used only in three cases,

```
// generic limitation
type A<T extends {}> = T
// ternary operator
type B = 'a' extends 'b' ? ( true ) : ( false )
// interface inheritance
interface C extends Node { }
```

In your case TS say's you were going to use #2 but didn't

You don't need `extends` there, it's inherited from `interface TestAgain<Props extends U>` the same way you don't define types of function arguments in function body

```
interface U {};
type Test<T extends U> = {};
interface TestAgain<Props extends U> {
  Component: Test<Props /* is extending U, so doesn't error */ >; // the closing tag of this line gives an error: '?' expected
}
```

(actually you have to make U non-empty for that to give error on improper use, as)

```
interface U { u: 'u' };
type Test<T extends U> = {};
interface TestAgain<Props /* not extends */ > {
  Component: Test<Props> // error: Props does not extend U, prop 'u' is not compatible
}
```